# In PHP, how do I check if user just visited the homepage/indexpage of the website?

Tags: php, session, authentication

I'm not talking about if user has visited the website before, but in general when a user (regardless if they've visited the website before) that's not logged in, has just visited the homepage of your website? I'm thinking it has to do something with sessions, but I haven't quite figured it out yet.

Comment: You could always use cookies, but they are not relieable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` that will return the last page's address visited. You can not rely on this for important things because this variable can be changed and might be not set by the user agent.

From the PHP documentation:

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

You could also use a cookie or a session variable and set the page visited like this:

```
// by file
setcookie('last_page', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
// by uri
setcookie('last_page', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

and check with:

```
// homepage
$home = 'home'; 
// check
if ($_COOKIE['last_page'] == $home) {}
```

**References**

- [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)
- [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)
- [$_COOKIE](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to leverage PHP's [Server Variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

```
$refer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

This can easily be spoofed by any user, but that's an easy way of doing it.

Comment: Make sure and do a htmlspecialchars() on that server variable because, as you said, it can be easily spoofed.

Comment: since the user can manipulate the page they came from before, whats a better approach?

Comment: There isn't really a better way.  With more and more websites using SSL (as they should) this becomes an even bigger problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a cookie with a timestamp on entering the index page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a surefire way (assuming user has cookies enabled), start a session and assign a variable like `$_SESSION['ref'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and check against your homepage url on subsequent pages that the user visits.